# How can I improve the UX of the following time picker. This should allow the users to set their weekly availability

Tags: web-app, layout, mobile-web, ux-designer, datetimepicker

Availability is Set

[image: Availabiltiy is set]

Availability is Not Set

[image: Availability is not set]

I am looking to improve the UI and UX of the following page where users can set their weekly availability for a meeting. I have attached 2 screenshots, one is when the availability is not set, the other is when it is set (tiles turn blue, from/to get filled, close button becomes red.).

My issue is that on smaller screens the list becomes scrollable and the save button goes down. How can I improve this?

Comment: What exactly is it you want improved? You want the Save button to always be visible? You don't want it scrollable?

Comment: Well, I was looking for ideas to make it entirely different. Currently it takes a lot of vertical space and the rest of the page is empty (this would be 1 issue). Then the fact that the list becomes scrollable, hides the save button and the users might miss saving their availability. Do you have any feedback please :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a save Button (and it should be disable if you didn't change anything by default).
Take inspiration from other apps, such as ios clock. You can have a switcher element instead of the "X" buttons (like an on/off) to set the availability.